# Gnuwin32 find.exe expands wildcard before performing search

Tags: find, expansion, gnuwin32

I am using Gnuwin32 binaries on a Windows environment.
When I want to find files of a certain type, let's say PDF, I usually run:

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' -print
```

This works perfectly on any UNIX system.

```
find.exe . -iname "*.pdf" -print
```

But under Windows, having replaced single quotes with double-quotes, *it only works when there is no pdf file in the current directory, otherwise the `*` gets expanded*.

Worse: when there is exactly one PDF file in the current directory, it will expand, there will be no syntax error and you will get wrong results.

I have tried escaping the `*` with a caret, a backslash, a star itself, putting inside double quotes: nothing works for me.

### Real example:

Okay, here are all my files:

```
C:\tmp>find . -type f
./a/1.pdf
./a/2.pdf
./a/aa/1.pdf
./b/1.pdf
./b/bb/1.pdf
./b/bb/2.pdf
```

Good behaviour, wildcard was not expanded

```
C:\tmp>find . -iname "*.pdf"
./a/1.pdf
./a/2.pdf
./a/aa/1.pdf
./b/1.pdf
./b/bb/1.pdf
./b/bb/2.pdf

C:\tmp>cd a
```

Caution, inconsistent behaviour, wildcard was expanded:

```
C:\tmp\a>find . -iname "*.pdf"
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]

C:tmp\a>cd ..\b
```

Caution, inconsistent behaviour, wildcard was expanded :

```
C:\tmp\b>find . -iname "*.pdf"
./1.pdf
./bb/1.pdf
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Why don't you want `*` to get expanded? If not, how do you think find shows you the results?

Comment: Because I want `find` to have argv[3] equal to `{'*','.','p','d','f'}`. Find is adult enough to interpret the jokers.

Comment: Example: I have `./a.pdf`, `./b/a.pdf`, `./b/b.pdf` ; I run `find . -iname "*.pdf"`. Cmd expands it to `find . -iname a.pdf`, and eventually I do not get `./b/b.pdf` in my results. Of course with a Unix shell, `find . -iname '*.pdf'` gets me all pdf files.

Comment: show your batch code in your question to better understand your situation

Comment: I run `find . -iname "*.pdf"` and i don't have problems. It will show me all my pdf files...

Comment: do you have one or more pdf files in your current directory?

Comment: @ghostdog74, I have included real examples for you to be able to figure it out.

Comment: [ezwinport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/)'s find (4.2.30) is also working as expected, more up to date than UnxUtils perhaps....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found myself the solution to my problem.

- Gnuwin32's `find.exe` is not working on recent Windows Versions (Vista, Seven) because it expands wildcards matching only the contents of the current directory.
- Similarly, an old version of find.exe from UnxUtils suffered the same bug.
- [The latest `find.exe` from UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) is working.

Comment: I got caught by this myself and answered another post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860141/windows-mingw-asterisk-passing-by-argv1-to-string/38098363#38098363) with the answer. For mingw, set a global "int _CRT_glob = 0;" in the same source file as main or Winmain. Globbing is then turned off. It's quite a shock for an experienced programmer the first time you see this happening!

Answer (score 18):

One workaround is to add a wildcard/expansion that the Windows shell does not expand, but GNU find does:

```
find.exe . -name *[.:]pdf -print
```

The Windows shell[*] does not interpret/expand square braces.  In addition, colon is not a valid character in Windows filenames, so this pattern *cannot* match any Windows filename, and the Windows shell will always pass the pattern through to find.exe.

Find.exe will then find any files ending in `.pdf` or `:pdf` , but since no files can have a name ending in `:pdf` under Windows, it will only find files ending in `.pdf`.

[*] It's actually the C runtime that does/not perform these wildcard expansions.  I don't understand the Win32 C runtime well enough to refine the distinction, so for now for the purpose of this workaround, I'm just saying 'shell'.

Comment: small nitpick: it's the C runtime which performs the expansion, not the shell.

Answer (score 3):

I suffered this problem this afternoon.
Benoit's UnxUtils can work.
I also find MinGW's find.exe can work,it is under my

> "MinGW\msys\1.0\bin"

directory. And it is  consistent with the manual.

> gnuwin32 and UnxUtils: `find.exe . -name GameCli*` work, but
>   `find.exe . -name 'GameCli*'` doesn't work.
>
> MinGW's `find.exe . -name 'GameCli*'` work.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found anything better than just avoiding wildcard characters

```
find.exe . -iregex ".+\.pdf" -print
```

Comment: Note: -iregex doesn't work on some versions of gnuwin32 find.exe [due to a bug](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-findutils/2005-07/msg00008.html)

Answer (score 0):

@OP, i have consistent behaviour

```
C:\test\temp>find . -iname "*.txt"
./1.txt
./2.txt

C:\test\temp>cd a

C:\test\temp\a>find . -iname "*.txt"

C:\test\temp\a>cd ..\b

C:\test\temp\b>find . -iname "*.txt"

C:\test\temp\b>find --version
GNU find version 4.2.20
Features enabled: CACHE_IDS D_TYPE
```

You may want to try to use [findutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) instead of UnxUtils.

Comment: Same. When I use `C:\gnuwin32\bin\echo.exe "*.txt"` it outputs `a.txt b.txt`. Maybe it is a cmd.exe setting?

Comment: ghostdog74: thee [this message](http://www.mail-archive.com/gnuwin32-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01582.html). What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I have found a solution for my problem, thank you for helping me diagnose it. Actually, it did not come from cmd.exe which never expands a `*` and lets programs do that themselves, but from `find.exe` which behaves differently on recent versions of Windows.