# windows mingw asterisk '*' passing by argv[1] to string

Tags: c, mingw, argv

I wrote a code below

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char cmd[50]="dir";
    if (argc == 2) {
        sprintf(cmd,"dir %s",argv[1]);
    }
    if (argc == 3) {
        sprintf(cmd,"dir %s %s", argv[1], argv[2]);
    }
    printf("%s\n",cmd);
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

when I executed like below

[image]

I think can't pass '*' by *argv[]

How can I pass something like "*.c" ?

update

code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char cmd[50]="dir";
    if (argc == 2) {
        sprintf(cmd,"dir %s",argv[1]);
    }
    if (argc == 3) {
        sprintf(cmd,"dir %s %s", argv[1], argv[2]);
    }
    if (argc > 3) {
        sprintf(cmd,"dir %s %s", argv[1], argv[2]);
    }
    printf("%s\n",cmd);
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

changing is below
[image]

what..... @.@ ?

Updated code again

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char sp[2]=" ", cmd[250]="dir";
    if (argc > 1) {
        sprintf(cmd,"dir /d ");
        for (i =1 ; i < argc; i ++)  {
            strcat(cmd,sp);
            strcat(cmd,argv[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",cmd);
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

see what happen when I executed

[image]

kind of ugly.... any decent idea?

Comment: I tried this on my Windows system (compiled with gcc from MinGW) and `*.c` is passed correctly.

Comment: edit your code to include `if (argc > 3)` case. Probably shell expansion is occurring

Comment: @nnn but mine don't correctly. :(

Comment: @M.M I add if (argc > 3) case. ls *.c  converting to dir cat.c copycon.c  what ....what's going on?

Comment: @alexparkjw post your updated code and screenshot, make sure you are running the updated code

Comment: What shell are you using?  Can you try `ls "*.c"`

Comment: @chqrlie the shell is cmd.exe (windows 10)

Comment: What happens if you quote `"*.c"` ?

Comment: @M.M I think buffer holds all of  *.c strings. what do you think?

Comment: @alexparkjw the updated version shows that the `argc > 3` case is actually happening

Comment: try `echo *.c`.  Does it display `*.c` or the list of C files?

Comment: @chqrlie echo *.c shows that *.c the same.

Comment: So it seems that cmd.exe is doing shell expansion on Windows 10, this doesn't happen on my system Windows 8.1

Comment: It would be surprising that Microsoft would introduce such a drastic change in Windows 10.  That would cause endless headaches as so many batch and command files rely on the previous behavior.  I suspect the C runtime is doing the expansion.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995493/gnuwin32-find-exe-expands-wildcard-before-performing-search

Comment: @chqrlie "*.c" ... this is working well what I expected.  but ugly

Comment: This will complicate your quick and dirty implementation of `ls`.  Especially since the stupid `dir` command cannot handle multiple arguments gracefully.

Comment: The ugly output is that of `dir`. You cannot implement a decent `ls` as a wrapper on top of such a braindead CMD.EXE built-in command.  You  will need to write some substantial amount of non trivial code to implement the `ls` unix utility.  If you just care about a single filespec, try to find a different toolchain that does not expand wildcards, such as Microsoft Visual Studio (I never thought I would ever give such advice!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is not related to the C runtime, but to the shell behaviour.  If you use Windows CMD.EXE, the * is passed unchanged to the programs, whereas if you use Cygwin's `bash`, the shell expands `*` to the list of files and passes this expansion as individual arguments to your program.  You can prevent this expansion by quoting the wildcards with `"*"` or `'*'`.

Note that you should not use `sprintf`, but `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflows.  If you link to the non standard Microsoft C library, you may need to use `_snprintf` instead.

EDIT: CMD.EXE does not seem to expand wildcards, but the C runtime you link your program with might do it at startup. See this question: [Gnuwin32 find.exe expands wildcard before performing search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995493/gnuwin32-find-exe-expands-wildcard-before-performing-search)

The solution is to quote the argument.

Comment: The OP seems to be using CMD.EXE. Cygwin would show the path as /cygdrive/d/system

Comment: He might be use a more advanced Windows shell that expands wildcards... Quoting the argument should fix the problem.

Comment: @chqrlie "quoting" helps but ugly, I just have to use the powershell. thank you for helping me once of all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the accepted answer is not correct as the edit courteously admits. What is happening here is that globbing behaviour is provided in the C runtime but the default behaviour *differs between compilers*.

Yes, it's a major pain if you do not know what is happening. Worse the globbing does not occur if the glob does not match any files. I was pretty surprised myself.

Under [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bch7bkk.aspx), by default, wildcards are *not* expanded in command-line arguments. You can enable this feature by linking with setargv.obj or wsetargv.obj:

```
cl example.c /link setargv.obj
```

Under MinGW, by default, wildcards **are** expanded in command line arguments. To prevent this you can link with CRT_noglob.o or, much more easily, add the *global* variable:

```
int _CRT_glob = 0;
```

in your own source in the file which defines main() or WinMain().