# FindUtils from gnuwin32 on Windows 7: simple pattern matching

Tags: shell, windows-7, command-line, gnuwin32

I'm trying to use `find` command from [FindUtils package from gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) with Windows 7 standard `cmd.exe` shell.

But when I type simplest possible command involving pattern matching, it doesn't work right.

If I type:

`find . -name "*.java"`

I end up with: `paths must precede expression` error. [Here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-findutils/2005-05/msg00421.html) I found folowing explanation:

> The -name test takes only one argument.  In your command line, the
>   shell is expanding the *s* into more than one argument before the find
>   command is run.   Therefore you get the error you see.  You should
>   either escape any shell metacharacters in the -name argument or
>   enclose that argument in quotes.

But I *am* enclosing that argument in quotes!

I tried also with single quotes:

`find . -name '*.java'`

In this case no files are found (there are plenty of .java files in directory, but I checked `'*'` for sure, with the same effect).

I also tried:

```
find . -name \*.java
```

With the same effect as for double quotes. The same for:

```
find . -name "\*.java"
```

What am I doing wrong? In [example I found](http://hexample.com/2012/02/04/findutils-find-locate-updatedb/), using double quotes with star worked well.

I think it may be related with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992125/gnuwin32-port-of-find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995493/gnuwin32-find-exe-expands-wildcard-before-performing-search?rq=1]) and [there](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuwin32/discussion/74807/thread/55face5c#b4ee). Seems to be related to GNUWin32's find.exe behaving different on Windows Vista and Windows 7 but not Windows XP.